# Python BeautifulSoup, parsing XML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract just the SQL error line:

```
SQL Error: failed
```

- however all text from `msg` tag is printed:

```
Test: 01
SQL Error: failed


Test: 01
SQL Error: failed
```

**file.xml**

```
<item>
<msg>
Test: 01
SQL Error: failed
</msg>
</item>
<item>
<msg>
Test: 01
SQL Error: failed
</msg>
</item>
```

**Code:**

```
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

file = "file.xml"

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    fobj = f.read()
    bobj = BeautifulStoneSoup(fobj)
    pattern = re.compile('SQL Error')
    for error in bobj.findAll('msg', text=pattern):
        print error
```

Comment: Beautiful Soup 3 has been replaced by Beautiful Soup 4. I suspect this can be made to work with the older version, but upgrading may get you more help with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it is supposed to be working - you are getting a `Tag` class instance as a result of `find_all()` call. Even if you print out the `error.text` - you'll get a complete text of the `msg` element:

```
Test: 01
SQL Error: failed
```

Assuming you want to extract the `failed` part, here is what you can do:

```
pattern = re.compile('SQL Error: (\w+)')
for error in bobj.find_all("msg", text=pattern):
    print pattern.search(error.text).group(1)
```

Here we are using [capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) to save one or more alphanumeric characters (`\w+`) after the `SQL Error:` text.

Also, you should definitely upgrade to [BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

And then import it as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 1):

Using BeautifulSoup 4 you can change

```
print error
```

to

```
print error.get_text().strip().split("\n")[1]
```

`error` is a tag, so you first get the string value from it with `get_text()`, the you have to strip off the leading and trailing carriage returns with `strip()`.  You then make an array with each value being a separate line, and the value you want is the second line so you access it with `[1]`.